# vim wildmenu: move into subdirectory with a different key than <down>

Tags: vim

This has been bothering me for quite a long time. I like to use wildmenu for browsing directories in command mode. The problem is that for entering into subdirectory I need to use `<down>` key which is always out of reach. I tried to make some mapping to overcome this issue but without success. For instance:

```
cnoremap <C-j> <DOWN>
```

But if I press `<C-j>` when I want to enter a subdirectory in wildmenu, the menu disappears and `^I` occurs at the end of the command line. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What about using `<c-n>` instead?

Comment: By default, `<C-n>` moves to an item to the right and if I try to map `<C-n>` to `<down>` the result is exactly the same as with `<C-j>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce this. It looks like command-line mappings (same with `<Tab>`, not just `<Down>`) aren't interpreted in wildmenu mode, and instead exit it and insert the `'wildchar'` literally. You can report this to the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php). I think additionally a `wildmenuvisible()` function analog to the `pumvisible()` would be needed, so that mappings could behave differently depending on whether the wildmenu is currently active.

You can work around the issue with `feedkeys()`, though:

```
function! EnterSubdir()
    call feedkeys("\<Down>", 't')
    return ''
endfunction
cnoremap <expr> <C-j> EnterSubdir()
```

Answer (score 5):

Christian Brabandt came up with a [different solution on vim_dev](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/c5fe5345be2e4786): For your original mapping to work, you need to set `'wildcharm'` to the same value as `'wildchar'`:

```
:let &wildcharm = &wildchar
:cnoremap <C-j> <DOWN>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was probably a bug which was fixed by the Vim patch [8.2.2221](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/b0ac4ea5e1c5f0ff4e951978c32ccfffe46916f8).